# Can't get a custom Font working

Tags: css, fonts

I'd need some help with custom fonts. For some reason I can't get them to work, I'm using a .css and I'm pretty sure I'm doing all as required. Here's my head link with .css :

```
<link rel=stylesheet type= "text/css" href= "main.css">
```

and my .css :

```
html, body {
    padding-top: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Dudu_Calligraphy';
    src: url(fonts/Dudu_Calligraphy.tff);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

p {
    font-family: Dudu_Calligraphy
    font-weight= 100;
}
```

both .html, .css, and the font are in one folder and i just can't apply them on the paragraphs

Comment: Do you get any 404 errors in your console? As far as I know, the extension of a TrueType Font should be **TTF** not **TFF**!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you misspelled a little, it should be `font-weight: 100;`, not `font-weight= 100;`.

You need multiformat fonts to use them in the web, because some browsers supports one type, some supports the another one.

Needed formats: TrueType, WOFF, EOT Compressed, SVG.

And your `@font-face` should look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FONTNAME';
    src: url('path/to/font/font.eot');
    src: url('path/to/font/font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    src: url('path/to/font/font.ttf') format('truetype'),
    src: url('path/to/font/font.woff') format('woff'),
    src: url('path/to/font/font.svg#FONTNAME') format('svg');
}
```

To generate different types of font, you can for example use this font generator: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

And if your fonts will not be rendered properly on all platforms, you can try this CSS rules:

```
* {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: yeah, i already fixed the misspelled code and it didn't work again, now i'll try the things you suggested, thanks anyways.

Comment: nope, still won't work .. I tried with both .woff and .woff2  
current .css : 
html, body {
 padding-top: 3em;
 text-align: center;
 width: 82%;
 margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'LiS';
    src: url('fonts/dudu_calligraphy-webfont.woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}
p {
    font-family: LiS
    font-weight= 100;
}